# How to write aspnetcore middleware that serves a UI

Tags: asp.net-core, middleware

What is recommend way to make a UI middleware in aspnetcore 3.1?

I'm trying to reproduce the functionality of middleware like squashbuckle where a consumer can import a NuGet package and then register it like:

```
app.UseMyCustomMiddleUI(c =>
{
    c.RoutePrefix = "custom/ui";
});
```

Navigating to `http://localhost:5000/custom/ui` would then serve the assets bundled in my NuGet package.

Specifically, how can I package assets such as css, js or even razor pages so that they are exposed at a certain path when the middleware is registered?.

People who have suggested the `static files` middleware. How does this work in the context of a NuGet package where I am not serving files from a file system, but rather files embedded in my assembly (I'm guessing)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1 this might help

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problem because it's hard to answer without details. Ar of right now, your questions looks like a classic case of  an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why does this needs to be a middleware? Why are static files not working for you?

Comment: I have updated the question to provide more details

Answer (score 5):

Basically you would need to add a `StaticFileMiddleware` with a route prefix. In your case, that prefix would be `/custom/ui`. You could then serve static files from your package using the middleware.

You can look inside the [SwaggerUI source code](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/SwaggerUIMiddleware.cs) to find how they did it.

I've adapted their code a little bit for your situation. It would look like this.

```cs
public class CustomUiMiddleware
{
    private const string RoutePrefix = "custom/ui";
    private readonly StaticFileMiddleware _staticFileMiddleware;

    public CustomUiMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next,
        IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _staticFileMiddleware = CreateStaticFileMiddleware(next, hostingEnv, loggerFactory);
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var httpMethod = httpContext.Request.Method;
        var path = httpContext.Request.Path.Value;

        // If the RoutePrefix is requested (with or without trailing slash), redirect to index URL
        if (httpMethod == "GET" && Regex.IsMatch(path, $"^/?{Regex.Escape(RoutePrefix)}/?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            var indexUrl = httpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl().TrimEnd('/') + "/index.html";
            RespondWithRedirect(httpContext.Response, indexUrl);
            return;
        }

        // Serve the index.html file
        if (httpMethod == "GET" && Regex.IsMatch(path, $"^/{Regex.Escape(RoutePrefix)}/?index.html$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            await RespondWithIndexHtml(httpContext.Response);
            return;
        }

        // Serve a static file or continue to the next middleware
        await _staticFileMiddleware.Invoke(httpContext);
    }

    private StaticFileMiddleware CreateStaticFileMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate next, 
        IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnv, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            RequestPath = $"/{RoutePrefix}",
            FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(CustomUiMiddleware).GetTypeInfo().Assembly),
        };

        return new StaticFileMiddleware(next, hostingEnv, Options.Create(staticFileOptions), loggerFactory);
    }

    private void RespondWithRedirect(HttpResponse response, string location)
    {
        response.StatusCode = 301;
        response.Headers["Location"] = location;
    }

    private async Task RespondWithIndexHtml(HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.StatusCode = 200;
        response.ContentType = "text/html;charset=utf-8";

        await using var stream = typeof(CustomUiMiddleware).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(typeof(CustomUiMiddleware), "index.html") ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
        var htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder(await new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEndAsync());
        await response.WriteAsync(htmlBuilder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
    }
}
```